# How to generate jacoco report in maven test phase

Tags: maven, junit, mockito, powermockito, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am using Mockito and Power Mockito in my unit test cases. I am able to generate the jacoco report when I run the profile code-coverage but

I am getting error when I try to generate Jacoco report in the test phase

**Error**
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.2:report (default-report) on project testproject-api: An error has occurred in JaCoCo report generation.: Error while creating report: Error while analyzing d:\workspace\api\target\classes\pkg\ResponseBuilder.class. Cannot process instrumented class pkg\ResponseBuilder.class. Please supply original non-instrumented classes. -> [Help 1]

**Code**
Please find the code below

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>code-coverage</id>
     <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
          <classifier>runtime</classifier>
          <version>${jacocoVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacocoVersion}</version>
            <executions>
              <!-- Off line instrumentation is needed to compute coverage for Power Mock tests -->
              <execution>
                <id>default-instrument</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>instrument</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>default-report</id>    
                <goals>
                  <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
              </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
              <!-- Workaround to https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=504 -->
              <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
              <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved now. I need to add test phase for default-restore-instrumented-classes goal. Please find the updated code

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Workaround to https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=504 -->
          <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
          <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>


<plugin>
<groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
<artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${jacocoVersion}</version>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>coverage-initialize</id>
    <goals>
      <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
  <execution>
    <id>default-instrument</id>
    <goals>
      <goal>instrument</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
  <execution>
    <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
    <phase>test</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
  <execution>
    <id>coverage-report</id>
    <phase>test</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>report</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```